# Check that record is successfully inserted in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I check if a record is successfully inserted in database using Doctrine in symfony2?

My action in controller is

```
public function createAction(){
    $portfolio = new PmPortfolios();
    $portfolio->setPortfolioName('Umair Portfolio');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($portfolio);
    $em->flush();
    if(){
         $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Record Inserted!");
    }else{
         $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Record notInserted!");
    }
}
```

What should I write in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could wrap your controller in a `try / catch` block like this:

```
public function createAction() {
    try {
        $portfolio = new PmPortfolios();
        $portfolio->setPortfolioName('Umair Portfolio');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($portfolio);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Record Inserted!");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('my_flash_key',"Record notInserted!");
    }
}
```

If the insert fails, an exception will be thrown and caught.  You will probably also want to log the error message inside your catch block somehow by calling `$e->getMessage()` and/or `$e->getTraceAsString()` which will explain the exception.

Comment: How can I display different divs in view according to success and fail of insertion?

Comment: Add a flash message with a different key - like setFlash('insert_failed', 'Your message') and in  your twig template do something like {% if app.session.hasFlash('insert_failed') %}<div class="error-message">{{ app.session.flash('insert_failed') }}</div>{% endif %}

Comment: Maybe you should call the rollback-method of your entitymanager in the catch-block. Just FYI

Comment: As far as I know, if flush() fails, the rollback will be done automatically.